# shortened output of property values in recursive function

Tags: powershell, namespaces, wmi

I want to recursively enumerated all WMI namespaces.
I have this function:

```
function Get-WmiNamespace {
  Param(
    [parameter()]
    [string]$Namespace = 'root',
    [parameter()]
    [string]$Locale = 'MS_409',
    [parameter()]
    [switch]$Recurse
    )
  Begin {
    $WMIParams = @{
      Namespace = $Namespace
      Class = '__NAMESPACE'
      Locale = $Locale
      ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
      }
    }
  Process {
    Get-WmiObject @WMIParams |
      Sort-Object -Property Name -CaseSensitive -Culture "en-US" |
        ForEach-Object {
          $WMIParams.Namespace = "{0}\{1}" -f $_.__NAMESPACE, $_.Name
          $object = [PSCustomObject] @{
            Namespace = $WMIParams.Namespace
            }
          $object.PSTypeNames.Insert(0,'Wmi.Namespace.Name')
          $object
          if ($recurse) {
            $PSBoundParameters.Namespace = $WMIParams.Namespace
            Get-WMINamespace @PSBoundParameters
            }
          }
    }
  }
```

Inspired here:
[https://learn-powershell.net/2014/05/09/quick-hits-list-all-available-wmi-namespaces-using-powershell/]

I get this output:

```
Namespace
---------
ROOT\Appv
ROOT\CIMV2
ROOT\CIMV2\mdm
ROOT\CIMV2\mdm\dmmap
ROOT\CIMV2\mdm\MS_405
ROOT\CIMV2\ms_405
ROOT\CIMV2\ms_409
ROOT\CIMV2\power
ROOT\CIMV2\power\m...
ROOT\CIMV2\power\m...
ROOT\CIMV2\Security
ROOT\CIMV2\Securit...
ROOT\CIMV2\Securit...
ROOT\CIMV2\Termina...
ROOT\CIMV2\Termina...
ROOT\Cli
ROOT\Cli\MS_405
ROOT\Cli\MS_409
ROOT\DEFAULT
ROOT\DEFAULT\ms_405
ROOT\DEFAULT\ms_409
ROOT\directory
ROOT\directory\LDAP
ROOT\directory\LDA...
ROOT\directory\LDA...
ROOT\Hardware
ROOT\Hardware\ms_405
ROOT\Hardware\ms_409
ROOT\Intel_ME
ROOT\IntelNCS2
ROOT\IntelNCS2\ms_409
ROOT\Interop
ROOT\Interop\ms_405
ROOT\Interop\ms_409
ROOT\Microsoft
ROOT\Microsoft\Hom...
ROOT\Microsoft\pro...
ROOT\Microsoft\Sec...
ROOT\Microsoft\Uev
ROOT\Microsoft\Win...
...
ROOT\Microsoft\Win...
ROOT\msdtc
ROOT\PEH
ROOT\Policy
ROOT\Policy\ms_405
ROOT\Policy\ms_409
ROOT\RSOP
ROOT\RSOP\Computer
ROOT\RSOP\User
ROOT\SECURITY
ROOT\SecurityCenter
ROOT\SecurityCenter2
ROOT\ServiceModel
ROOT\StandardCimv2
ROOT\StandardCimv2...
ROOT\StandardCimv2...
ROOT\StandardCimv2...
ROOT\StandardCimv2...
ROOT\subscription
ROOT\subscription\...
ROOT\subscription\...
ROOT\WMI
ROOT\WMI\ms_405
ROOT\WMI\ms_409
```

Namespaces names are truncated.
I guess the reason is the width of Name column is set in first iteration of function `Get-WmiNamespace` according longest value (`ROOT\SecurityCenter2`).

It can be fixed by piping output to `Format-Table` with `-AutoSize` parameter:

```
Namespace
---------
ROOT\Appv
ROOT\CIMV2
ROOT\CIMV2\mdm
ROOT\CIMV2\mdm\dmmap
ROOT\CIMV2\mdm\MS_405
ROOT\CIMV2\ms_405
ROOT\CIMV2\ms_409
ROOT\CIMV2\power
ROOT\CIMV2\power\ms_405
ROOT\CIMV2\power\ms_409
ROOT\CIMV2\Security
ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm
ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption
ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices
ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices\ms_405
ROOT\Cli
ROOT\Cli\MS_405
ROOT\Cli\MS_409
...
```

What would be the best way to solve this behavior?

Comment: FWIW it's actually `Format-Table` that truncates the values in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

The entire name is stored in the namespace property. If you just want to see it in the command output,  you could use `-ExpandProperty` from `Select-Object`

`Get-WmiNamespace -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty namespace`

Also, just adding `Sort` shows the full name

```
Get-WmiNamespace -Recurse | Sort
```

Comment: My point was whether there is a way to modify function itself to get table formated without shortening them when there is enough free horizontal space on the console and without a need to pipe it through next Format-Table or whatever.

Comment: You may create your own custom format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms714665(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#defineobjectformatting

Answer (score 0):

Without using Expand and Doug is points out, you can just dot it and avoid the format stuff or futzing with trying to change the function itself, etc. Well, at least for a single column.

```
(Get-WmiNamespace -Recurse).Namespace
# Results
<#
 (Get-WmiNamespace -Recurse).Namespace
ROOT\Appv
...
ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm
ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption
ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices
ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices\ms_409
...

ROOT\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement15
ROOT\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement15\MS_409
ROOT\Microsoft\SqlServer\ServerEvents
ROOT\Microsoft\SqlServer\ServerEvents\MSSQLSERVER
...
ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\DesiredStateConfigurationProxy
ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\DesiredStateConfigurationProxy\MS_409
...
#>
```

If you saying you want, like a Linux column file list of these then other steps are needed You can do this Linux like multi-column using the Format-Wide cmdlet.

For Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files' -Recurse | 
Format-Wide -Property Name 

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files' -Recurse | 
Format-Wide -Property Name -Column 5
```

So, for this list to get a table-like view, do the same thing.

```
Get-WmiNamespace -Recurse | 
Format-Wide -Property namespace -Column 3
# Results
<#
ROOT\Appv                                              ROOT\aspnet                                            ROOT\CIMV2                                           
ROOT\CIMV2\mdm                                         ROOT\CIMV2\mdm\dmmap                                   ROOT\CIMV2\mdm\MS_409                                
ROOT\CIMV2\ms_409                                      ROOT\CIMV2\NV                                          ROOT\CIMV2\NV\Events  
....
#>
```

Use whatever column count that fits your screen. No, you cannot use columns and autosize together as they are mutually exclusive.

So, as Doug points out you can make your own formatter, or as per your comment...

> 'My point was whether there is a way to modify function itself to get
> table formated '

...you can doctor the function to use aforementioned for the results you are after.